# How to run tests from the custom jar inside maven project?

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, testing, jar

I have created custom jar with repository (MyRepo), model (MyClass) and some tests (MyTests).

This is the test class in my custom jar:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = MyApp.class)
public class MyTests{

private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext context;

@Autowired
private MyRepo myRepo;

@Before
public void init() throws Exception {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(context).apply(springSecurity()).build();
}
```

And tests in that class look like this one:

```
@Test
@Transactional
@Rollback
public void test1() throws Exception {
    MyClass user = myRepo.find(ID);
    .....
    mockMvc.perform(post(myRequest)
                .contentType(CONTENT_TYPE)
                .content(user))
                .andExpect(status().is(MY_STATUS))
                .andExpect(content().contentType(CONTENT_TYPE))
                .andExpect(content().json(MY_RESPONSE.toString(), false));

}
```

I have added this jar into maven project as dependency.

Is it possible to somehow configure and change MyTests class or something inside jar, so that I can run those tests (MyTests) in the test part of the maven project, in which I have added this jar as dependency. I would like to call these test, for example, like this:

```
@Autowired
MyTests myTests;

.....
myTests.runAllTests();
```

Can anyone tell me how to do such a thing?

I want those tests from the jar to run and test my maven project and its database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {                    
       JUnitCore.main(
         "TestCase1");            
}
```

**OR**

Double check the url to see if case.jar is where you claim. Also check if `TestCase1` class is in any package. e.g. if `TestCase1` is in package comp.lang.java and under the folder comp/lang/java/ of case.jar root, then you need to write:

```
loader.loadClass("comp.lang.java.TestCase1");
```

example:

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;
import junit.framework.TestResult;
import junit.textui.TestRunner;
public class MyTestRunner {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
URL url = new URL("file:///d:/case.jar");
URLClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{url});
loader.loadClass("TestCase1");
TestRunner runner = new TestRunner();
TestResult result = runner.start(new String[]{"TestCase1"});
System.out.println(result.toString());
}
}
```

Comment: With this the WebApplicationContext inside class MyTests, inside jar, is going to be WebApplicationContext of the jar and not app, in which I have added this dependency, right?